# Iterative loading from source in wpf ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a public observable collection named XModelCollection which is bind to a ItemsControl in WPF. When the view loaded I have inserted data from my global collection to XModel collection. At the beginning the global collection doesn't have a lot of data, the data increase with scrolling.

```
XModelCollection = GlobalCollections.XModels;
```

When I switch to another view to save memory, I clean the XModel.

```
XModelCollection = null
```

But when I come back to that view I reassign values of XModel from the global collection. The functionality is okay. But now the global collection have so many data like thousands, so the view becomes freeze for 3-4 seconds.

```
XModelCollection = GlobalCollections.XModels;
```

How can I avoid the freezing ? What would be the perfect approach for iteratively loading data to the source from another collection ?

Comment: Try to us a **ItemsPanelTemplate** with **VirtualizingStackPanel** that should not freeze your app.

Comment: Okay I am looking into it. Any particular source for study ?

Comment: Have look at [wpf-tutorial.com](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/)